# RAID vs software defined Block Storage

Tags: raid, storage

As far as I understand was `RAID` invented to protect from hardware failure induced data loss:

- Say, you have 2 harddrives in `RAID1`, one goes south, lucky you, the other one got your data.
- Say you want better storage capacity than `RAID1` and have no special requirements for write access, there is `RAID5` waiting. One Disk goes bust. Lucky you swap it out, wait until reconstruction is done. Everything is fine

On the other hand there is software defined `Block Storage` which abstracts from nitty gritty details of hardware. In principle does it something quite similar: Storing information redundant across several physical drives.

In which scenarios are `RAID`-Solutions still the way to go?

Comment: For the sake of accuracy, block storage in a fairly generic concept that describes storage systems that write blocks to disks, etc. RAID arrays use provided block devices (disks) to create an abstraction that is also a block device. You can have long complicated stacks of local or clustered block devices via RAID, LVM, DRBD, etc. Block devices are always logical abstractions, either of other underlying block devices in a chain or of actual hardware like spindles. It sounds like you're using "block storage" to refer to SDS - and while that's technically not wrong, it's more generic than that.

Comment: I am using `block storage` indeed as synonym for "software defined storage".

Comment: I updated my question reflecting software defined block storage.

Comment: are you calling ZFS "block storage"?

Comment: @aaaaaa Perhaps there is a confusion on my side regarding the terms. In general I was wondering whether or not RAID is still a thing today and how is it in comparison to something like Ceph which is something I would call (perhaps not correctly) an object / block storage. And for lack of better word, I contrasted "RAID" and "Block storage" - not knowing, that the term is polysem. And under some circumstances it might be okay calling ZFS a block storage. But I do not know, honestly ;)

Comment: Oh, i see. that might be my ignorance too. I guess, RAID is a term useful on single-computer level. It might be different levels of abstraction. My guess, Seph can and should be run on hardware that has RAID. ZFS, for instance, is implementing software RAID

Comment: @aaaaaa AFAIK the point is here, that you run Ceph on commodity hardware without RAID. If a drive failes, information is still present in the cluster. So Ceph - as I understand it - replaces the need for RAID - therefore my question ☺️

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> to protect from hardware failure induced data loss:

No. RAID is intended to reduce downtime, not data loss. For data loss protection you are supposed to keep backups.

> On the other hand there is Block Storage which abstracts from nitty gritty 
>   details of hardware. In principle does it something quite similar:

No. Block storage - the term in itself - makes no guarantees about redundancy. Many block storage devices can implement redundancy, but it is up to the user to do it and not necessarily required.

> In which scenarios are RAID-Solutions still the way to go?

This is a VERY good question. Less and less, I would assume. Generally RAID gave better possibly performance due to hardware write back caching. That said, today I build a distributed (multiple computer) block storage with terabytes of fast SSD write cache based on a 2x100 gigabit crosslink from every server - there is no RAID card on the market that can keep up with that, including uptime (because my RAID 1 actually is mirrored on servers).

I would say the air for RAID hardware is getting thin.

Btw., RAID 5 you can pretty much forget for large discs - anything above 2TB is too risky, RAID 6 will cover you for a little more space but it tops out too.  Further reading - https://www.zdnet.com/article/has-raid5-stopped-working/

Comment: Just to amplify Tom's point - do not use R5 please, it's been essentially dead for a decade, it's borderline negligent of controller vendors to still be offering it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I updated my question, adding "software defined", to remove ambiguities.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what did you use to build that distributed block storage?

Comment: +1 First time i see "downtime vs dataloss". Usually people just brush aside saying "RAID is not backup" but never elaborate what it is

Comment: @Halfgaar Windows Server Datacenter. Which is very expensive, except this particular setup is under MSDN licensing as it is a Hyper-V Cluster for R&D. A machine has 512gb memory, 2x16 cores Epyc (+hyperthreading) and 10 disc slots. 4xSSD, 4x2TBHDD and 2x1.6TB U.2 SSD as cache. Network is 2x100gb, 3 machines planned for now in a triangle on the network (so no switch). Budget per machine is (uincluding some money for a switch) €15k

Comment: I'd add that with todays multi-TB drives, a replacement drive under RAID5/6 takes ages to build, and performance degradation while that happens is significant.

Comment: The air for RAID *hardware* may be getting thin, but not for RAID in general.  A distributed replicated multi-terabyte block storage is far more expensive than a simple mirrored pair of hard drives, and there are a lot of companies whose only downtime-avoidance need is to keep the financial data available in the event of a disk failure.

Comment: Well, this only makes sense as a question if you assume "RAID" is "hardware". And there it STILL makes less and less sense. Software RAid is getting better and a decent block storage part of every windows server (not even getting into Linux and ZFS). Given the price ofa dedicated RAID card - small setups made no sense 10 years ago and make zero now. Just plug in some SSD, use software mirroring and be done. Or use mirrord hard discs and plug an SSD as buffer in front - instead of spending more money on a RAID controller. But mostly: THe OP question makes only sense when you talk about HW.

Comment: @TomTom yes. That was the context which I had in mind. It could be rephrased to: What once was done in hardware (the kind of RAID I had in mind) is now done better in software (not necessarily called RAID - I used "Block Storage" with something like Ceph in mind)? And my limited understanding of the whole topic and lack of precise terms let me phrase the question like above. But thanks to all participants I learned a lot :-)

Answer (score 3):

Hardware (i.e. self-managed) RAID are usable, when:

1. the physical maintenance is about to be done by some less-qualified "remote hands" staff. "Pull the drive with LED blinking and replace with the new one please".
2. the hardware itself might contain additional safeguards, like battery to ensure the buffers are actually written to the disks after the system is rapidly powered down.